# Powerful units in Rome Total War?

Tags: cheats, rome-total-war

There is a cheat in Medieval Total War 2 where you get [powerful units](http://m2tw.warlore.org/units/Mercenary_Rocket_Launcher) by entering Houston in the console. Is there a cheat like this for Rome Total War?

Comment: I know you can have oliphaunts which can break through any army but I was wondering if there was a siege weapon version of this.

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals It is a cheat, where you type Houston and gain this :http://m2tw.warlore.org/units/Mercenary_Rocket_Launcher?campaign=crusades

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is basically no.  There is a cheat to make certain units bigger and there is a cheat to make unite cheaper. After a quick search I found this for you, hope it helps ;)

http://www.cheatcc.com/pc/rometw.html